# How to interpret DKIM x-tag and t-tag in gmail message source

Tags: gmail, dkim

After having configured DKIM **several months ago** for a specific domain, i notice the following which i cannot explain.
DKIM has been configured with the following relevant (for this question) tags:
- the t (created time) tag
- the x (expired time) tag

The t-tag announces the epoch time when the key has been created. The x-tag announces the epoch time when the key expires (assuming i have my information correct.

Today, sept 5th i sent 2 emails (test and test2) from that specific domain to my google account. When looking at the source of the message, i see the following information related to the specified tags:

test:
t=1504598567 (human time: GMT: Tuesday 5 September 2017 08:02:47)
x=1536134567 (human time: GMT: Wednesday 5 September 2018 08:02:47)

test2:
t=1504600505 (human time: GMT: Tuesday 5 September 2017 08:35:05)
x=1536136505 (human time: GMT: Wednesday 5 September 2018 08:35:05)

In my assumption the t-tag should be the same in both messages: the epoch time or seconds since the epoch time the signature has been created. On the other hand, the difference between the current time and the expiration time (the x-tag) should vary.
In this situation, where t is always equivalent to the current time, the signature would always be valid. In our configuration, the expiraiton time has been set to 1 year. So regarding the tag values in gmail, the signature will always be valid for 1 year.

My question: do i interpret the information correct, or is something wrong in how gmail interprets the DKIM tags (t, x).

Answer (score 0):

In the [DKIM RFC 6376](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#page-24) I can not find the mention of any relation between the time of the key creation and either the `t` or `x` tag in the signature. They are the creation/expiration time of the *signature*, not the key.

**`t` tag (Signature Timestamp):**

> The time that this signature was created.

So this value should change (unless both messages were signed at the same second), even if the same key is used.

**`x` tag (Signature Expiration):**

> Signatures MAY be considered invalid
> if the verification time at the Verifier is past the expiration
> date.